# How do I convert HH:MM time format to decimals in SSRS?

Tags: reporting-services, time-format

How do I convert HH:MM time format to decimals in SSRS? So for example 3:30 becomes 3.5, 3:15 becomes 3.25.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works on some sample data for me, hopefully you can apply it to your data. Assuming your field is called `MyTime`:

```
=CDec(IIf(Instr(Fields!MyTime.Value, ":") = 2
    , Left(Fields!MyTime.Value, 1)
    , Left(Fields!MyTime.Value, 2)))
    + CDec(Right(Fields!MyTime.Value, 2)) / 60.0
```

[image]

This takes the two strings on either side of the colon, transforms them into numbers, divides the minutes portion by zero then adds them back together. Works OK for me.

Comment: Brilliant. Worked great.  Thanks Ian.